# Change item through fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to create a star button in javascript that will append to the list of the important items when you click it. But when I am clicking on the button, and as you can see, after I ask to change 'important' to true, I ask to print if it is false or true, but it continues to print false even though I have changed it to true. What am I doing wrong?
I will appreciate any help

```
 const second_element = document.createElement('div')


 second_element.innerHTML = `<div style="display: inline-block; width: 5%;"> <button style="background-color: ${read}"> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-star" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
    <path d="M2.866 14.85c-.078.444.36.791.746.593l4.39-2.256 4.389 2.256c.386.198.824-.149.746-.592l-.83-4.73 3.522-3.356c.33-.314.16-.888-.282-.95l-4.898-.696L8.465.792a.513.513 0 0 0-.927 0L5.354 5.12l-4.898.696c-.441.062-.612.636-.283.95l3.523 3.356-.83 4.73zm4.905-2.767-3.686 1.894.694-3.957a.565.565 0 0 0-.163-.505L1.71 6.745l4.052-.576a.525.525 0 0 0 .393-.288L8 2.223l1.847 3.658a.525.525 0 0 0 .393.288l4.052.575-2.906 2.77a.565.565 0 0 0-.163.506l.694 3.957-3.686-1.894a.503.503 0 0 0-.461 0z"/>
    </svg> </button> </div>`;

second_element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("clicked")
    fetch(`/emails/${email.id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          important: true
      })
    })
    .then( () => { 
      console.log(email.important)
      load_mailbox('inbox')
    })
  })

document.querySelector('#container').append(second_element);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is You are attempting to read values from the same state before. You need return the newly updated entity/object as a response to you update request, then handle the response and pdateing local state. In the backend side, somene  has to write code that updates item with the flag important = true. Then yo wirte code to return this updated entity, this way your frnt end has to where to know what changed:

//implement in the backend the return of a result containing the
recently updated entity.

//then, handle the response value in the frontend:

```js
  .then( (response_here ) => { 

      //read the response

      if (response.status === 200 )//ok
      {
           //success - go to next part of the business flow
      }

      console.log(email.important)
      load_mailbox('inbox')
    })
```